# How to redirect in ajax after successfully post of data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am submitting form data using Ajax and they are successfully saved in the database and I am able to alert the response data. I now want to use the returned data as response to call another function using Ajax and pass them as parameters so that to the called function they can be used to fetch data and and display them on the web page.

The problem is that when the data have been alerted, the function I call using Ajax is not responding even when I use some functions like `window.location.href`, `window.location.replace`, `window.location.reload` they are not executed

Here is the sample code

```
submitHandler: function(form) {
    /*errorHandler.hide(); */

    var el = $(div);
    el.block({
        overlayCSS: {
            backgroundColor: '#fff'
        },
        message: '<i class="fa fa-refresh fa-spin"></i>',
        css: {
            border: 'none',
            color: '#333',
            background: 'none'
        }
    });
    /*Set off for database validation */
    $('#name1').removeClass('has-error');
    $('#name1 .help-block').empty();
    $('#date1').removeClass('has-error');
    $('#date1 .help-block').empty();
    /*end database validation */

    /*ajax options */
    var options = {
        /*target:        '#output2',    target element(s) to be updated with server response */
        success: function(data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
            el.unblock();
            if (!data.success) {
                /*append error message on the form for each control and database validation*/
                console.log(data);
                if (data.errors.name1) {
                    $('#name1').addClass('has-error');
                    $('#name1 .help-block').html(data.errors.name1);
                }
            } else {
                var business_id = data.business_id;
                var bnm_app_id = data.bnm_app_id;
                var name = data.name;
                var doc = data.doc;

                alert(business_id);
                alert(bnm_app_id);
                alert(name);
                alert(doc);

                if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                    myObject = new XMLHttpRequest();
                } else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
                    myObject = new ActiveXObject('Micrsoft.XMLHTTP');
                    myObject.overrideMimeType('text/xml');
                }

                myObject.onreadystatechange = function() {
                    data = myObject.responseText;
                    if (myObject.readyState == 4) {
                        //document.getElementById('step-2').innerHTML = data;
                        window.location.reload(true);
                    }
                }; //specify name of function that will handle server response........

                myObject.open('GET', '<?php echo base_url()."bn_application/register";?>?bnm_app_id=' + bnm_app_id + '&doc=' + doc + '&business_id=' + business_id + '&name=' + name, true);
                myObject.send();


            }
        },
        error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            el.unblock();
            if (xhr.responseText === undefined) {
                $.gritter.add({
                    /* (string | mandatory) the heading of the notification */
                    title: 'Connection timed out',
                    class_name: 'gritter-black'
                });
            } else {
                var myWindow = window.open("Error", "MsgWindow", "width=900, height=400");
                myWindow.document.write(xhr.responseText);
            }
            /*clear controls that do not need to keep its previous info */
        },
        url: home + 'bn_application/save_clearance_name',
        /* override for form's 'action' attribute*/
        data: {
            name1_percent: name1_percent
        },
        type: 'post',
        /* 'get' or 'post', override for form's 'method' attribute*/
        dataType: 'json',
        /* 'xml', 'script', or 'json' (expected server response type)*/
        beforeSend: function() {

        },
        uploadProgress: function(event, position, total, percentComplete) {

        },
        complete: function() {

        }
    };
    /*submit form via ajax */
    $('#bn_clearance').ajaxSubmit(options);
}
```

Comment: Please show the code that you have tried.

Comment: Debugging help questions require a [mcve] as per the [help]. Your code is not minimal. Please [edit] your question to make sure that your code is Minimal (only the code necessary to reproduce your issue in your question), Complete (users do not need anything else to reproduce your issue), and Verifiable (the provided code does reproduce the exact issue you are facing). As it is your question is off-topic for Stack Overflow. Note that this is also a common [downvote reason](http://idownvotedyoubecause.com/so/TooMuchCode).

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you right , you need something like this ?

```
   $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: baseUrl + 'api/cars',
    success: function (firstResponse) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: baseUrl + 'api/cars/' + firstResponse[0].Id,
            success: function (secondResponse) {
                window.location.href = secondResponse[0].Make;
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use window.open function

```
$("button").click(function(){
    $.ajax({url: "demo_test.txt", success: function(result){
       $("#div1").html(result);
       window.open("http://www.w3schools.com", "_self");
    }});
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You should put your redirecting url in `success` function of ajax. (if you are using jQuery). Because javascript runs codes asynchronously and probably your code tries to run before you get response from request.